# Настройка сервера django + apache2

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi, mod-wsgi

Как правильно настроить связку *python 3.4 + django + apache 2.2 + virtualenv*?

Установлены *python 2.7* и *python 3.2*, в виртуальном окружении установлен *python 3.4*. По `127.0.0.1:8000` сайт работает.

Как теперь открыть доступ извне для сайта?

Сейчас пытаюсь запустить чистый *django*, т.е. тестовую страницу.
Делаю так: запускаю апач в виртуальном окружении, он запускается без ошибок, пишет только:

> Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Запускаю *runserver* для *django* (использует *python 3.4*) - тестовая страница django открывается, а извне — ошибка 500.

Конфиг апача:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  myproject
    ServerAdmin mail@list.ru
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject processes=1 maximum-requests=1 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/www/myproject/logs/myproject.error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/myproject/logs/myproject.access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
    <Directory "/var/www/myproject/src">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Стуктура проекта:

```
/var/www/myproject

..../static_content

..../src

......../myproject

............manage.py

............/myproject

...............django.wsgi  (использую сейчас)  

...............settings.py       

...............urls.py

...............wsgi.py (был изначально)   

.../logs

.../env

......../bin
.............activate
.............activate.csh
.............activate.fish
.............django-admin
.............django-admin.py
.............easy_install
.............easy_install-3.4
.............pip
.............pip3
.............pip3.4
.............python -> python3.4
.............python3 -> python3.4
.............python3.4 -> /usr/local/opt/python-3.4.3/bin/python3.4

......../include

......../lib

......../docs
```

django.wsgi:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
site.addsitedir('/var/www/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/sitepackages')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

wsgi.py (сейчас не используется, был изначально, с ним тоже не работало):

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

В логах апача пишется: `[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u1 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/3.2.3 configured -- resuming normal operations`

В myproject.error.log:

```
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Create interpreter 'myproject|'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3770, process='myproject', application='myproject|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1]   File "/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [error] [client ::1] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Maximum requests reached 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Shutdown requested 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Stopping process 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Destroying interpreters.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Destroy interpreter 'myproject|'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client ::1] Zlib: Compressed 614 to 376 : URL /
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Terminating Python.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:22 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3770): Python has shutdown.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Attach interpreter ''.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Create interpreter 'myproject|'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3854, process='myproject', application='myproject|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1]   File "/var/www/myproject/src/myproject/myproject/django.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [error] [client ::1] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Maximum requests reached 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client ::1] Zlib: Compressed 614 to 376 : URL /favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Shutdown requested 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Stopping process 'myproject'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Destroying interpreters.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Destroy interpreter 'myproject|'.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Terminating Python.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:23 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3854): Python has shutdown.
[Tue Jul 28 19:04:24 2015] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=3860): Attach interpreter ''.
```

Comment: Вот не надо запускать апач в virtualenv, нормальная конфигурация подразумевает запуск отдельного сервера (gunicorn, uwsgi, что-то ещё) в virtualenv, а апач/nginx только перенаправляют на него запросы

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за замечание, теперь запускаю апач вне virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум если вы хотите всё сделать на python3, то вы окружение вы делаете неправильно. В python 3 окружение ставится через внутренний модуль venv, а не через сторонние скрипты virtualenv (это всё описано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)). Virtualenv с ним больше не работает, параметр python= нужен в случае если у вас несколько вторых питонов.

Дополнительно можете ознакомиться с ответом [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/537471/176345)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/89581)

Comment: @Denis Дополнил

Answer (score 0):

> ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

вероятно, стоит добавить в конфигурацию *apache* такую директиву:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/myproject/env
```

добавлять её следует в «глобальную» конфигурацию сервера (за пределами блоков `virtualhost`) — таков [контекст её использования](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome).

p.s. на основании [этого ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14927454/4827341).

Comment: Добавил директиву, выдает ошибку: `WSGIPythonHome cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
Action 'configtest' failed.`

Comment: добавил в ответ упоминание про контекст.

Comment: Теперь выдает ошибку: `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named encodings`

Comment: вероятно, в созданном вами *environment* нет такого модуля. если вы не знаете, как с этим быть – задавайте *новый* вопрос по этому поводу.