# Как задать настройки версии python для Django?

Tags: python, django, wsgi

Используется хостинг SWEB, на нем необходимо развернуть Django проект с третьей версией python.

Создал виртуальное окружение

```
 virtualenv env --no-site-packages python=python3.3
```

Настроил `.htacess`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddHandler wsgi-script .py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/c/login/site-dir/public_html/project/wsgi.py/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Настроил `wsgi.py`

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/new_cys/public_html')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/new_cys')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/env/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

С такими настройками сайт работает, но не работают некоторые библиотеки (например `pillow`), `DEBUG` выводит информацию о том, что django использует python версии 2.7, а тот же самый `pip install` естественно устанавливает библиотеки под версию 3.3 и как я полагаю из-за этого возникают проблемы в работе этих библиотек.

При активации окружения и запуска python запускается естественно python3.3
Подскажите какие манипуляции еще необходимо выполнить что бы Django использовал python версии 3.3

Comment: Очевидно, сам сайт в апаче запускается вне виртуального окружения, надо mod_wsgi вроде настраивать, но по-моему лучше использовать nginx+gunicorn

Comment: лучше использовать nginx+uwsgi+supervisor

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/new_cys/public_html')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/new_cys')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/login/site-dir/env/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/')

virtualenv = os.path.join('< path/to/virtualenv_python3.3_dir >', 'bin', 'activate')
try:
    exec(compile(open(virtualenv).read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except:
    pass

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но к сожалению не помогло...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых в python 3 окружение ставится через внутренний модуль venv, а не через сторонние скрипты virtualenv (это всё описано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)). Virtualenv с ним больше не работает, параметр python= нужен в случае если у вас несколько вторых питонов.

Соответственно команда для создания виртуального окружения будет

```
python3 -m venv myenv
```

Дальнейшие действия, вроде source и установки пакетов аналогичны.

Во-вторых, все библиотеки вроде PIL имеются в репозитории и скомпилированы для вашего дистрибутива (укажите какой у вас). В debian/ubuntu наличествуют пакеты python-imaging (для PIL). Ну и да, тогда создавать виртуальное окружение надо с параметром --system-site-packages.